# JavaFX 8 - How to initizalize CSS of custom control when its constructor is invoked

Tags: css, javafx-8

I'm programming a custom control using JavaFX, particularly a custom button.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    public MyButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/mystyle.css").toExternalForm();
        getStyleClass().add("my-button");
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

Inside mystyle.css I have the following CSS rules

```
.my-button {
    -fx-background-color: gray;
    -fx-background-radius: 2;
}
```

Then in the start method I added the button to the stage in this way

```
VBox root=new VBox();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

MyButton button=new MyButton("Click me");

root.getChildren().add(button);
stage.setScene(scene); // stage is the name of Stage parameter
stage.show();
```

The button looks like this

[image]

Now if I add under the button constructor the code

```
button.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
    Color.YELLOW, new CornerRadii(20), new Insets(0,0,0,0)
)));
```

the button still looks the same, instead it should be like this

[image]

I think the problem is that CSS class is applied after a certain delay, so when the stylesheet is applied override the background specified manually.

What I want is a way to apply CSS directly inside the constructor. Is it possible?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try calling `applyCSS()`?

Comment: Inside the constructor? Yes, I did but nothing changes, the button still remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Stylesheet using the getUserAgentStylesheet() method.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
private final String STYLE_SHEET="/mystyle.css";//Your Stylesheet

  public MyButton(String text) {
      super(text);
      getStyleClass().add("my-button");
  }

  //This method will do the job
  @Override
  public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
      return STYLE_SHEET;
  }
}
```